# Bootstrap layout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML layout structure defined as below;

```
<div class="span9">
    <div style="margin:10px"><h4>Header 1</h4></div>
    <div id="globalInfo" style="height:260px"></div>
    <div style="margin:10px"><h4>Header 2</h4></div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="lowerGrid" style="width:850px; height:200px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am also using Bootstrap 2.3.2

Now "globalInfo" div and lowerGrid gets populated on render after API call.

My issue is that I have given globalInfo an initail height of 260px...But there are some form elements (textbox) inside "globalInfo" and on user actions like invalid input, I show an error div dynamically which increase the height of globalInfo and that causes some issue with the lower div .

Actually "Header 2" changes it's position and moves to the right when the additional error div gets displayed under globalInfo ?

How do I fix the issue ? I have to give a static height for globalInfo initially...so cannot remove that to fix this.

Comment: jquery or source please

Comment: can you generate the issue in fiddle